# With activerecord, how do I do a .find using an array of ids when I know that some may be missing?

Tags: activerecord

I have an array of ids. Some may be in my table, some may not. I want to return the ones in the table and then create rows for missing ones. If I do a Model.find(array) I get an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exception if any of them are missing. The workaround I'm using is to do a .exists? for each id, but this makes for many db calls, slowing things down.

Is it possible to do a Model.find(array) without having to test each one with .exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like find_by_id has been deprecated, but it got me looking in the right direction. Model.where(id: array) seems to do the trick.

Comment: Indeed `find` and `find_by_id` are just wrappers for where.limit(1).... More interestingly I found out that `Where  id in(1, 2, 3, 888888)` will only return existing records in one shot.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `find_by_id` ActiveRecord will not throw an error and SQL will only collect the existing ids.

```
Model.find_by_id(array)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like find_by_id is deprecated in rails 4.